# about array declaration in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

hay, i have 2 array like this

```
  foreach($kelas as $value)
    {
        $siswa[] = Siswa::whereIn('id', $data[$value->nama_kelas])
                        ->with(['ortuwali', 'wali', 'pribadi', 'penyakit'])
                        ->with('riwayat_pendidikan')
                        ->with(['ijazah' => function($q){
                        // $q->with(['nilaiujianakhir'])
                            // ->with(['mapelujian' => function($q){
                                // $q->select('mapelujian.nama_mapel','nilaiujianakhir.*')
                                $q->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', 'nilai_ujian.mapel_id')
                                // ->join('mapelujian','mapelujian.id','nilaiujianakhir.mapel_ujian_id');
                            // }])
                            ->get();
                        // $q->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', 'nilai_ujian.mapel_id')->get();
                        }])
                        ->with(['nilaiujianakhir' => function($q2){
                            $q2->join('mapel_ujian', 'mapel_ujian.id', 'nilai_ujianakhir.mapel_ujian_id')->get();
                        }])
                        ->with(['kelas' => function($q) {
                            $q->with(['ptk', 'sikap', 'prestasi'])
                              ->with(['pembelajaran' => function($q) {
                                $q->select('pembelajaran.*', 'mapel.id as mapelid', 'mapel.urut_rapor')
                                    ->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', '=', 'pembelajaran.mapel_id')
                                    ->with('nilai.kkm')
                                    ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(mapel.urut_rapor), CAST(mapel.urut_rapor AS DECIMAL) ASC');
                              }])
                              ->orderBy('semester_id');
                        }])
                        // ->with(['kelas.ptk','kelas.sikap', 'kelas.prestasi'])
                        // ->with([
                        //     'kelas.pembelajaran' => function ($q) {
                        //         $q->select('pembelajaran.*', 'mapel.id as mapelid','mapel.urut_rapor')
                        //           ->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', '=', 'pembelajaran.mapel_id')
                        //           ->with('nilai.kkm')
                        //           ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(mapel.urut_rapor), CAST(mapel.urut_rapor AS DECIMAL) ASC');
                        //     }
                        // ])
                        ->orderBy('nama')
                        ->get();
    }

  $siswa[] = Siswa::whereIn('id', $pindahan)
                    ->with(['ortuwali', 'wali', 'pribadi', 'penyakit', 'riwayat_pendidikan'])
                    ->with(['ijazah' => function($q){
                        // $q->with(['nilaiujianakhir'])
                            // ->with(['mapelujian' => function($q){
                                // $q->select('mapelujian.nama_mapel','nilaiujianakhir.*')
                                $q->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', 'nilai_ujian.mapel_id')
                                // ->join('mapelujian','mapelujian.id','nilaiujianakhir.mapel_ujian_id');
                            // }])
                            ->get();
                        // $q->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', 'nilai_ujian.mapel_id')->get();
                    }])
                    ->with(['nilaiujianakhir' => function($q2){
                        $q2->join('mapel_ujian', 'mapel_ujian.id', 'nilai_ujianakhir.mapel_ujian_id')->get();
                    }])
                    ->with(['kelas' => function($q) {
                        $q->with(['ptk', 'sikap', 'prestasi'])
                          ->with(['pembelajaran' => function($q) {
                            $q->select('pembelajaran.*', 'mapel.id as mapelid', 'mapel.urut_rapor')
                                ->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', '=', 'pembelajaran.mapel_id')
                                ->with('nilai.kkm')
                                ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(mapel.urut_rapor), CAST(mapel.urut_rapor AS DECIMAL) ASC');
                          }])
                          ->orderBy('semester_id');
                    }])
                    // ->with(['kelas.ptk','kelas.sikap', 'kelas.prestasi'])
                    // ->with([
                    //     'kelas.pembelajaran' => function ($q) {
                    //         $q->select('pembelajaran.*', 'mapel.id as mapelid','mapel.urut_rapor')
                    //         ->join('mapel', 'mapel.id', '=', 'pembelajaran.mapel_id')
                    //         ->with('nilai.kkm')
                    //         ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(mapel.urut_rapor), CAST(mapel.urut_rapor AS DECIMAL) ASC');
                    //     }
                    // ])
                    ->orderBy('nama')
                    ->get();
```

and i merge array **siswa** with this function

```
$siswas     = new Collection;

    foreach($siswa as $value)
    {
        $siswas = $siswas->merge($value);
    }
```

in blade i call object like this for each relation

```
 $siswa->pribadi->berat_badan_diterima
$siswa->pribadi->berat_badan_keluar
$siswa->pribadi->tinggi_badan_diterima
```

and i get error **trying get property berat badan diterima of non object**

i already chage my code in blade file like this below format :

```
 $siswa->pribadi['berat_badan_diterima']
$siswa->pribadi['berat_badan_keluar']
$siswa->pribadi['tinggi_badan_diterima']
```

and **code works**,, but its not efective, i must change many line in blade file and many file blade for change the format,, i want changing code from controller this code..

```
$siswas     = new Collection;

foreach($siswa as $value)
{
    $siswas = $siswas->merge($value);
}
```

how to change the code controller above so that no errors occur **trying get property of non object**?

Thanks

Comment: could you try $object = json_decode(json_encode($siswas), FALSE); ?

Comment: // Merge seluruh array dari $siswa
        $siswas     =  json_decode(json_encode($siswas), FALSE);

        foreach($siswa as $value)
        {
            $siswas = $siswas->merge($value);
        }

like this ?

Comment: no before you pass the $siswas variable into the view, conver it first

Comment: example code from my code plis,,

Comment: i got error undefined variable $siswas

Comment: before you return your siswas to blade, execute it first $siswas   = json_decode(json_encode($siswas), FALSE);

Comment: i use this code

 $siswas = new Collection;
        foreach($siswa as $value)
        {
            $siswas = $siswas->merge($value);
        }

  $siswas     =  json_decode(json_encode($siswas), FALSE);
 

but when i click button print pdf.. error intenalserver error 500,,

Comment: i already follow your code , but i got new error , intenal server error 500.. do you know ?

Comment: Internal error maybe because you are already accessing values in different ways, just try to access it without pressing the button print pdf

Comment: i already dd() $siswas,, but same internal server eror 500

Comment: why not change the query to include both results? this way it does not need to do 2 queries, and you don't need to combine the results manually, and it could also be faster since you'll end up with fewer latency point (but this is depends on your query speed)

Comment: example from my code,, plis